# react-router, routes not working

Tags: react-router

I am using the react-router and I have the following routes

```
<Route path = '/' component = {App}>
    <Route path = '/login' component = {LoginContainer}>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Now from the app when I go to 'http://localhost' then it works fine, however when I navigate to http://localhost/login then I get an error saying login cannot be found.

Comment: what sort of history are you using?
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using webpack dev server, you will need to use the [History API Fallback](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option) option if you want to use browser history.

Basically, when you go to http://localhost/login, the dev server does not have anything at that address to serve you, so you need to tell it to fallback to your index to allow it to load the correct route.