# Why the react route not working in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is the content of pages/index.js as below:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,History, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import TestSocket from '../components/testSocket/TestSocket';
export default function Index(){
    return(
        <Router>
          <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/a' component={TestSocket}/>
          </Switch>
       </Router>
   )
}
```

When I access the page http://localhost:3000/a, the browse show

```
404 This page could not be found.
```

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354961/react-router-routes-not-working) is asking the same problem, however, it did not show how to solve the problem explicitly.

Would you help to elaborate more about the solution?

Comment: Please read `nextjs` routing system first.

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a symbolic (i.e. /pages/a.js) target to /components/testSocket/TestSocket.js?

Comment: That's right. Next.js has a file-system based routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) in `Next.js` is completely different like in `React.js.`
The first biggest difference, in `Next.js`, is the **lack of** a `react-router-dom` and its functions (BrowserRouter,History, Switch, Route)

> Next.js has a file-system based [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) built on the concept of pages.
>
> When a file is added to the pages directory, it's automatically
> available as a route.
>
> The files inside the pages directory can be used to define most common
> patterns.

Here You have best source how to solve Your issue, and help to migrate from `React.js` router to `Next.js` routes. [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router)

Comment: Do you mean I cannot map the path `/a` to the TestSocket component?

Comment: @TheKNVB it means that the way you do in react.js will not work in next.js, be patient and read the sources I sent you... ;-) the migration process is explained very well .