# Routes not working in react even when trying to use Routes and Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm following this tutorial: https://ibaslogic.com/routing-with-react-router/

When I render the page, I recieve this error

```
Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
    at invariant (bundle.js:61876)
    at Route (bundle.js:62025)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:23504)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:26266)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:27465)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:12454)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:12503)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:12563)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:32305)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:31141)
```

I've tried to wrap the `Route` in `Routes` as the warning suggests. I still get an error that I need `Router` which I already have. I've also tried the suggestions here [react-router, routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354961/react-router-routes-not-working) without success

Here is my js component file where the error is taking place:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import TodosList from "./TodosList";
import Header from "./Header";
import InputTodo from "./InputTodo";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import "./App.css"
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"

const TodoContainer = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getInitialTodos())

  const handleChange = id => {
    setTodos(prevState =>
      prevState.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed,
          }
        }
        return todo
      })
    )
  }

  const delTodo = id => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.id !== id
      }),
    ])
  }

  const addTodoItem = title => {
    const newTodo = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: title,
      completed: false,
    }
    setTodos([...todos, newTodo])
  }

  const setUpdate = (updatedTitle, id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.title = updatedTitle
        }
        return todo
      })
    )
  }

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log("test run")
  
  //   // getting stored items
  //   const temp = localStorage.getItem("todos")
  //   const loadedTodos = JSON.parse(temp)
  
  //   if (loadedTodos) {
  //     setTodos(loadedTodos)
  //   }
  // }, [])

  function getInitialTodos() {
    // getting stored items
    const temp = localStorage.getItem("todos")
    const savedTodos = JSON.parse(temp)
    return savedTodos || []
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // storing todos items
    const temp = JSON.stringify(todos)
    localStorage.setItem("todos", temp)
  }, [todos])

  

  return (
    <Route path="/">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="inner">
          <Header />
          <InputTodo addTodoProps={addTodoItem} />
          <TodosList
            todos={todos}
            handleChangeProps={handleChange}
            deleteTodoProps={delTodo}
            setUpdate={setUpdate}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Route>
  )
}

export default TodoContainer
```

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
//component file
import TodoContainer from "./functionBased/components/TodoContainer"
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"

//stylesheet
import "./functionBased/App.css"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <TodoContainer />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

I'm unsure how to make `Route` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to declare your `Route` in the `Routes` component. So you should first wrap the `TodoContainer` in the `Routes` component and then put the element you want to render in the `element` property of the `Route` component

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<TodoContainer />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Then, you don't need to handle the routing anymore in the `TodoContainer`

Take a look at the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial) to learn more about routing (this is the react router v6 here)

Comment: Thank you everyone -- all your suggestions were helpful....

Comment: 's suggestion did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the problem correctly but maybe try in the index.js to change

```
<TodoContainer />
```

with:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<TodoContainer />}/>
```

also remember to import Route from react-router-dom

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

This blogpost by Esteban Herrera gives a good example on how to use react router.
https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-dom-tutorial-examples/

Comment: I will check that blog post out, @jamie... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like that:

- remove Route tag from your component folder
- add Route tag to your index.js file like that

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

...

 <Router>
     <Route exact path="/" element={<TodoContainer />}/>
 </Router>
```